# Jenkins Slave on Windows Server 2016 on EC2 failing

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have setup a jenkins slave on an Amazon EC2 m4.large instance with Windows 2016 on it.

**Starting the jenkins slave over the browser** works fine. I see the tools folder being create inside the c:\jenkins folder and later on the repository gets cloned. So far so good.

Then the jenkins projects fails with following error message:

`ERROR: Failed to download https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/groovy-binary-2.4.3.zip from agent; will retry from master
java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: C:\jenkins-test\tools\hudson.plugins.groovy.GroovyInstallation\Groovy_2.4.3 at hudson.remoting.Channel@260f290a:slave-windows-ci: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine`

`wget https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/groovy-binary-2.4.3.zip`

Succeeds pretty fast in powershell.

**Letting the EC2 Amazon Jenkins plugins start the Windows Slave** works fine. I see the tools directory being create, but not hudson log file written into the tools directoy. (The tools directory holds a copy of the JDK used to execute the jenkins projects). But then I don't see any git repository being cloned.

Then the build executes forever on the slave. When I cancel the build following error appears: java.io.IOException: Connection aborted 
[image: Error message after killing the build]

Jenkins version: Jenkins 2.23

Java Version: JDK 8.0_102

Thank you very much for your help.